# how to use AutoHotKey to create a certain code

Tags: screen, autohotkey

How can I change the functions in the function row (F1-F12) of a computer's keyboard using the program called AutoHotKey?

I want two pieces of code to do the following:

1. Fn+F7 = screen off (*)
2. Fn+F10 = mouse keypad off

Note (*): I found some programs to let me turn off the screen with multiple shortcuts but the problem is that these programs turn off the screen completely which is not what I want. I want the screen to dim beyond limits when I press Fn+F7 (makes it look like it went off when it is not really off), and then when I press Fn+F7 again it returns to the way it was.

Comment: Well Mostafa, here I am. Yes you can program almost every possible key combination EXCEPT two: the [Fn] key and the [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del] combination. Below, I'll describe how to turn your screen off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to turn your screen off, I installed a small utility from NirSoft called nircmd.exe.

This is the code that I use:

```
!d:: ; The trigger combination is [Alt]+d
MonitorOff:
    run, "C:\Program Files\MyPrograms\nircmd.exe" monitor off
return
```

Comment: If your PC's Bios provides a way to turn your screen or mousepad off with an internal tool, them by all means try that. I have not searched for a tool that turns your mousepad off. Since many Laptops have a (non Microsoft) mousepad configuration utility, you could check if your specific mousepad utility supports a command line string to turn the mousepad on/off.

Comment: I found a way to turn my mousepad off . thank you for your advice